# How to access an object using a variable string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object whose name is mural.  I have assigned the name mural to the title of an anchor element.  When user clicks and element I want to store the title of the anchor in a variable called sprite.  I then want to access that object whose name corresponds to the sprite variable string.

Here is my code:

```
var mural= new Object();
mural.top='0px';
mural.left=-'510px';

var stamps= new Object();
stamps.top='0px';
stamps.left=-'1886px';

var sprite=$(this).attr('title');

$(".image-holder").css("background-position",'sprite.top, sprite.left');
```

It's not working because the the variable sprite is just a reference to $(this).attr('title'), how do I make it reference the object?

Oh and I know that .css jquery statement probably wont work, I'm not sure yet of the correct way to have two values that don't need quotations in as the second argument.  But I am mainly concerned with the way to get access to the object.

Comment: the title element is not for storing data :(

Comment: I know, but it does actually describe the picture contained within the anchor.  How else would you suggest I do it?  I'd like to know a better, more efficient way.

Comment: just define the css for it in the stylesheet?

Comment: the css for it changes depending on what has been clicked, that's why I have to change it via js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation, e.g. if `stamps` and `mural` are global objects:

```
var sprite = window[$(this).attr('title')];
```

JavaScript does not parse strings for variable substitution, you have to use string concatenation as the others already showed:

```
.css("background-position", sprite.top + ' ' + sprite.left);
```

---

But depending on the context, maybe it is possible to just use CSS:

```
.mural {
     background-position: 0px 510px;
}

.stamps {
     background-position: 0px 1886px;
}
```

JS

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(".image-holder").addClass($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

---

If this is not possible, I would actually store both sprites in a map:

```
// in some higher scope
var sprites = {
    mural: {
        top: '0px',
        left: '510px'
    },
    stamps: {
        top: '0px',
        left: '1886px'
    }
};

// in your event handler
var sprite = sprites[$(this).attr('title')];
```

But without knowing more about the context it is difficult to give a better suggestion.

Comment: Thats great thanks.  I have gave them classes on click which has a style associated with it in the stylesheet.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I finally know what you are aiming for. Please refers to Felix Kling's answer (the `window[$(this).attr("title")]` part.) and I think his meets your need. :-)

---

Replace `'sprite.top, sprite.left'` into `sprite.top + "," + sprite.left`

Properties of elements cannot store any variable, but only string.

If you want a dynamic access to the `mural` Object, just replace sprite into mural from above.

Therefore, I assume that you want an access to the data of mural Object instantly at clicking the element.

JSON.stringify(mural) and save to the title property of the A Element.

When it needs to be extracted, simply `spite = JSON.parse($(this).attr("title"))` and get that time of Object.

More than this, I suggest you to store it in a new variable instead of storing it at title property if I meet your real expectation.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know anything about referencing the object?  sprite.top is currently returning 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use object literals (I'll assume `=-` is a typo):

```
var mural = {top:'0px', left:'510px'};
var stamps= {top:'0px', left:'1886px'};

var sprite = this.title;
```

I would assume that the above will set `sprite` to be a string primitive, therefore it is unlikely to have a top or left property, but presuming you fix that and `sprite` is an object (or perhaps you meant to use `mural` or `stamps`), then:

```
$(".image-holder").css("background-position", sprite.top +
  ' ' + sprite.left);
```